# Python: Recursing (no loops or lists it must strictly stay as a string) a string to sum a net score between vowels/consonants(upper and lower case)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

In better detail

1. lowercase vowels (aeiou) are worth +1
2. lowercase consonants (i.e. the remaining letters from the English alphabet) are worth -1
3. uppercase vowels are +2 while uppercase consonants are -2

My code so far I don't where I am going wrong as I keep getting error..

```
def count_vowels(s):
    lower_vowels = 'aeiou'
    upper_vowels = 'AEIOU'
    if s[0] == '':
       return 0
    elif s[0] in lower_vowels:
       return 1 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    elif s[0] in upper_vowels:
       return 2 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    elif s[0] not in lower_vowels:
       return -1 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    elif s[0] not in upper_vowels:
       return -2 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    else:
       return count_vowels(s[1:])
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: 4th branch will never be executed. Think about that. Anyway, your base case should be empty string. When the function receives empty string as an argument it should return `0`. Otherwise it'll throw `IndexError`.

Comment: @MarcosModenesi - ahh I see what you mean I changed the else statement to another elif where s[0] cannot be in the upper_vowels and the else statement just returns the recursive call from s[1:] however I am still receiving an error when I try a simply test like 'dog'

Comment: Maybe you are missing the case where the character is not even a vowel. Remember you have `isupper()` and `islower()`

Comment: What is the boolean value of `s[0] not in lower_vowels` when `s[0] in lower_vowels` is `False` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  "I keep getting error" is not a problem specification.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_vowels(s):
    lower_vowels = 'aeiou'
    upper_vowels = 'AEIOU'
    if len(s) == 0:
        return 0
    if s[0] in lower_vowels:
       return 1 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    elif s[0] in upper_vowels:
       return 2 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    elif s[0].isupper()
       return -2 + count_vowels(s[1:])
    else:
       return -1 + count_vowels(s[1:])   
print count_vowels('efghjgbfvjhvbj')
```

Comment: 4th branch will never be executed.

Comment: That's part of the problem and my get rid of the Exception but apart from that as Marcos said, the algorithm is also not correct.

Comment: @trixn can you specify where the mistake is or how I can fix it?

Comment: Some of your conditions are incorrect. I'm sure you will find the problem. Think about this: What is the boolean value of `s[0] not in lower_vowel` when `s[0] in lower_vowels` is `False` ?

Comment: `elif s[0] not in lower_vowels:` codeflow will reach this elif only if s[0] is not a vowel(upper or lower). For all other letter(consonants-upper or lower will contribute -1 which is faulty

Comment: @IshuGoyal Thanks I understand now. I appreciated. I know how to fix everything!

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
from string import ascii_letters # all letters
vowel="aeiouAEIOU"

def net_score(text):
    if text: # the same as len(text)!=0
        c = text[0]   
        if c in ascii_letters: # this is to help ignore non-letters like spaces, ".,!" etc
            s = 1 if c.islower() else 2 # the value of the letter depending on if is upper or lower
            if c in vowel:
                return s + net_score(text[1:])
            else:
                return -s + net_score(text[1:])
        else: # in case of a non-letter continue with the next
            return net_score(text[1:])
    else: #base case
        return 0
```

a quick test

```
>>> net_score("Hello World!")
-6
>>>
```